# freezing progressbar before updating listview

Tags: android, listview, progress-bar, adapter

i want to show an circle before updating the listview , everything is working fine, while doinbackground of async task fetch the data from server it shows the progressbar but while updating the listview it freezes for sometime and then listview is shown, i want to remove that freezing of progressbar before updating, here is my code

```
 public class feeds extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>{


                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    // SHOW THE SPINNER WHILE LOADING FEEDS
                    linlaHeaderProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    
                }

                @Override
                protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    new_request_feeds(); //here i am fetching data from server
                    return fetch;
                }

                protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {

                    // HIDE THE SPINNER AFTER LOADING FEEDS
                    linlaHeaderProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                     if(result.size()!=0)
                   {
                         adapter=new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), R.id.list_ongoing, result);

                           list.setAdapter(adapter);               

                   }
                   else
                   {   


                       Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "no feeds", 3000).show();
                   }// Here if you wish to do future process for ex. move to another activity do here



                }
```

my getview()

```
  @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final int pos=position;
    System.out.println(position);
    View v = convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi =
            (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.feed_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
       holder.like=(ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.like);
        holder.share=(ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.share);
        holder.report=(ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.report);
        holder.headline_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lar);
        holder.topic_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.mt);
        holder.count_likes = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.count_likes);
        holder.count_shares = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.count_shares);
        holder.image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img1);
        holder.image2 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img2);
        v.setTag(holder);

    }
    else
        holder=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();

    mSharedPreferences= v.getContext().getSharedPreferences("mypref", 0);

         holder.headline_text.setText("  "+entries.get(pos).get(TAG_FFN)+" had a chance with "+entries.get(pos).get(TAG_IFN)+"!  ");
           holder.topic_text.setText(entries.get(pos).get(TAG_TOPIC));
           holder.image.setTag(entries.get(pos).get(TAG_FTID));
           holder.image2.setTag(entries.get(pos).get(TAG_ITID));
           holder.count_likes.setText(entries.get(pos).get(TAG_LIKERS)+" likes");
           holder.count_shares.setText(entries.get(pos).get(TAG_SHARERS)+" shares");

           if(entries.get(pos).get(TAG_LIKED).equals("True"))
            {
                 holder.like.setImageResource(R.drawable.like);                     
                 holder.like.setTag("True");
            }
           else
           {
               holder.like.setTag("False");
           }
           if(entries.get(pos).get(TAG_SHARED).equals("True"))
            {   

                 holder.share.setImageResource(R.drawable.share);   
                 holder.share.setEnabled(false);

            }


       //=======================setting image of user==========================================//
         // Loader image - will be shown before loading image


           // whenever you want to load an image from url
           // call DisplayImage function
           // url - image url to load
           // loader - loader image, will be displayed before getting image
           // image - ImageView 


          imgLoader.DisplayImage((image_url.getimage(Long.parseLong(entries.get(pos).get(TAG_FTID))))[0],loader, holder.image);           
          imgLoader.DisplayImage((image_url.getimage(Long.parseLong(entries.get(pos).get(TAG_ITID))))[0],loader, holder.image2);

    //====================================================================================// 



          holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if((holder.image.getTag()).equals(mSharedPreferences.getString("USERID", null)))
                    {

                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Your profile", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    Intent i=new Intent(v.getContext(),OtherProfilePage.class);
                    i.putExtra("Image_id",entries.get(pos).get(TAG_FTID));  
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    (v.getContext()).startActivity(i);

                    }

            }
            });

          holder.image2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(holder.image2.getTag().equals(mSharedPreferences.getString("USERID", null)))
                    {

                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Your profile", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    Intent i=new Intent(v.getContext(),OtherProfilePage.class);
                    i.putExtra("Image_id", entries.get(pos).get(TAG_ITID));

                    (v.getContext()).startActivity(i);

                    }

            }
            });

           holder.like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(holder.like.getTag()=="True")
                {
                     holder.like.setImageResource(R.drawable.like_pressed); 
                     holder.like.setTag("False");
                    new sendlikes().execute("link");

                }
                else
                {   holder.like.setImageResource(R.drawable.like);
                    holder.like.setTag("True");
                    new sendlikes().execute("link");
                }


        }
        });
           holder.share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.share.setImageResource(R.drawable.share);
                holder.share.setEnabled(false);
            new sendlikes().execute("http://gangster.cloudapp.net/share/",entries.get(pos).get(TAG_CID),mSharedPreferences.getString("person_id",null));


        }
        });

       return v;
      }
```

imageloader is a class that i used for caching the images.

Comment: try dismisiing after setting adapter

Comment: @user1920666  i have done it but not worked

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this line `linlaHeaderProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);` after `if` and `else` blocks. Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue could lie in a couple places:

1) You're doing a good deal of pre-processing of data in you Adapter's constructor.

Remember that everything in onPostExecute() runs on the application UI thread, so if your constructor for your adapter does some heavy processing, it could lock up the UI thread.

Creating an adapter can be done in doInBackground and then passed as the result to onPostExecute so that the setAdapter call is the only call there.

2) Your getView() method in your adapter isn't very efficient.

When you call setAdapter, the AdapterView must call getView for every cell that's going to be shown on screen. If there are a lot of cells and you're doing a lot of expensive operations like inflating views or findingViewsById, you could be locking up the UI thread for that initial load.

How's your scrolling performance? If it's lacking, the getView() would be the first place to start and I would watch Romain Guy's great talk on ListView performance for recommendations on how to create a good, efficient adapter.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Comment: yes my scrolling performance is not good as well, even i am using view holder and caching the images inside the adapter but still performance is not good enough

Comment: i have tried to set my adapter inside do in background but it gives me error here is my code......protected CustomListAdapter doInBackground(Void... params) {
         new_request_feeds();
         adapter=new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), R.id.list_ongoing, fetch);
         return adapter;
        }

Comment: Yeah, you can't set the adapter in doInBackground, but what you're doing above looks right, assuming you're not doing anything in your CustomListAdapter constructor that requires being on the UI thread.

I think you need to profile your getView() method to take a look at what operations you may be performing on the UI thread that could be slowing things down enough to cause the UI hiccups.

http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html

Comment: in my customlistadapter i have bunch of if else condition inside getview() and i am seeting item based on the values stored inside the fetch hashmap.

Comment: any chance we could see your getView() or the constructor of your CustomListAdapter?

Comment: There's nothing immediately obvious to me in your getView() that would be causing the hiccup, sorry.

Use the method profiling tools above to look for a method that's taking longer to run than you may expect and then look into optimizing your code.

The problem is definitely an operation that's taking too long on your UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

add a listener when onpostexecute is completed in listener onsuccess method in your activity set adpater and then dismiss progress it will work

Answer (score 0):

in you activity add this interface

```
public interface asyncListener{
        public void onSucess(Object  object);
        public void onFailure(Exception  exception);
    }
```

and add a varible

```
asyncListener as= new asyncListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSucess(Object object) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };
```

send this varible(listenr) in construtor in your asynctask contruct asign this to yourlistener in onpostexecute write `yourlistener.onSucess(result);`

Comment: the onsucces method will be called when onpostexecute is entered you can write your methods in onsucess

Comment: show your progress dialog in your activity before task.execute called and dismiss in onsucess method after setting adpter